# Convert CURL command to POST Python requests with form parameter

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

I'm a requests/python noob.I've figured out GET requests no problem but can't find out how to code those -F parameters properly with POST

http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/

I'm trying to figure out how I can make requests take care of a POST request that includes form data?

```
curl -X POST "https://falcon-sandbox.com/api/v2/submit/file?_timestamp=1548810863364" -H  "accept: application/json" -H  "user-agent: Falcon Sandbox" -H  "api-key:xxx" -H  "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "file=@test.pdf;type=application/pdf" -F "environment_id=160"
```

Comment: can you replace `  -F 'file=@test.pdf;type=application/pdf' \` with `  -F file=@/<path-to-file>/test.pdf \` and check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import requests

session = requests.Session()

headers = {'accept' : 'application/json',
           'user-agent': 'Falcon Sandbox',
           'api-key':'xxx',
           'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}

data = {'enviroment_id' : '160'}
files = {"file": open('test.pdf', "rb")}


session.post("https://falcon-sandbox.com/api/v2/submit/file", headers = headers, data = data, files = files)
```

Hopefully I haven't missed anything, but the structure should be the same.

Comment: Thanks..But I'm getting http error 400 43. Could it be because I'm missing this part of the code? `;type=application/pdf`

Comment: In general, requests would fill out the required headers (api key, and another specific  headers should fill out), so this case something other could be the problem.

Comment: I have edited my code, please check out again, I have tested it, it throws me an Invalid api key error, so the request is fine, I just don't have api key.